# EnumWindows returns incorrect handles in x64

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

I'm trying to get list of windows (in Win8.1 x64), using Delphi XE7u1.

Simple code

```delphi
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Winapi.Windows;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);

  function EnumWinProc(AHandle: HWND; Param: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
  var
    Buf: array[0..255] of WideChar;
  begin
    Result := True;
    GetClassName(AHandle, @Buf, 255);
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append(Buf);
  end;

begin
  EnumWindows(@EnumWinProc, 0);
end;


end.
```

works as expected while compiled for 32-bit platform, but not work while compiled for 64-bit platform (in this case AHandle is always zero in EnumWinProc).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Another FAQ. Do not use nested procedure for the callback.

Comment: Shame on me. Problem solved.

Comment: Here is one duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10162749/960757. There will be more of them...

Comment: These endless stream of nested function questions ;-) would never have happened if Emba have defined EnumWindows (and all other functions with callbacks) properly and had not made such a balls up of the `@` operator when applied to functions.